# Vmware Workstation - Cannot open disks xxxx or one of the snapshot disks it depends on

Tags: virtual-machine

I'm running Centos7 using Vmware workstation on windows 7 laptop. All was well until I restarted my laptop this morning & my VM started complaining as below

```
The parent virtual disk has been modified since the child was created. The content ID of the parent virtual disk does not match the corresponding parent content ID in the child

Cannot open the disk 'C:\Users\<user>\Documents\Virtual Machines\CentOS 64-bit\CentOS 64-bit-000003.vmdk' or one of the snapshot disks it depends on.

Module 'Disk' power on failed.

Failed to start the virtual machine.
```

Below is the image of the folder containing the VM & the image of the VM itself.

I've looked through the vmware log & found the disk ID

```
2016-03-21T15:56:15.685+13:00| vmx| I125: DISKLIB-LINK  : Opened 'C:\virtmac\CentOS 64-bit.vmdk' (0xe): monolithicSparse, 419430400 sectors / 200 GB.
2016-03-21T15:56:15.685+13:00| vmx| I125: DISKLIB-LINK  : DiskLinkIsAttachPossible: Content ID mismatch (parentCID b0f614a0 != a0549cb5)
```

[image: Vmware workstation error]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

All you have to do is to delete the .lck file from the folder of your vmdk files.
It is generally present at
C:\Users\UserName\Documents\Virtual Machines\VMWareName

Also you can just move the lck files one folder up to ensure you do not delete any other file by mistake.

Comment: I Remove all lck ( there was 3) folder , and its solved . thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Deleting all .lck files in the folder should technically solve the problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you use VMs such as Kali Linux, it might happen that the AV quarantines parts of the .vmdk files. In my case I had to restore it from the Windows Defender quarantined files [see the screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HsMIm.png)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Kali in VM,

1. Go to the main directory (Configuration File).
2. Determine the missing file partition. Ex: kali-linux-2022.3-vmware-amd64-s003.vmdk
3. Copy any other partition and give it a name of a messing partition.
   `> copy kali-linux-2022.3-vmware-amd64-s004.vmdk kali-linux-2022.3-vmware-amd64-s003.vmdk`

---

In case you face a Busybox Initramfs Error

- type `(initramfs) fsck /dev/sda1 -y`

Answer (score 2):

I got the same issue. Tried deleting the .lck folder and still didn't work. I then created a new snapshot and then started the machine and it finally worked.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34716995)